# How to query MySQL to fetch values whose similar or exact to the one being searched preoritazing on exact value?

Tags: php, mysql

How to query MySQL to fetch values whose similar or exact to the one being searched preoritazing on exact value. If exact value is found, do not fetch similar ones. Also, all that case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Full text search with relevance will help you here is the mysql manual on the subject http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html